# How do I set up my application so identity and domain objects are in the same context?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, structuremap

I'm using and MVC 5 project and I'm trying to set up my application's context so that it uses the identity context and applications domain context as one context.  I'm a little newer to dependency injection and I think I may have made a mistake somewhere that is causing these not to work properly.  I've seen numerous answers stating that you just need to create two connection strings, one that is an entity framework connnection string, and one that is a plain of sql connection string.  Then pass the sql connection string to your context and somehow MVC will know which one to use.  I thought it may been related to the fact that I was using a containerscoped, container per request application db context but when removing the container scope constraint it is still failing.

When I use the sql connection string I get an error saying applicationUser is not part of the current context, but the domain objects seem to query fine.  When I use my entity framework connection string, the context.Users object is empty indicating identity stuff isn't working.  Where am I going wrong?  If you need additional code information let me know and I will post it.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=HUNTER-PC;database=SteadyHOPS;integrated security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ApplicationDbContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.SteadyHOPS.ADO.csdl|res://*/Data.SteadyHOPS.ADO.ssdl|res://*/Data.SteadyHOPS.ADO.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=HUNTER-PC;initial catalog=SteadyHOPS;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

public interface IApplicationDbContext
    {}

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // I put these lines here to resolve and error about not being able to resolve the key
        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserLogin>().HasKey(r => new { r.LoginProvider, r.ProviderKey, r.UserId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<C__RefactorLog>().HasKey<Guid>(r => r.OperationKey);


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }


    public virtual DbSet<C__RefactorLog> C__RefactorLog { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<FieldType> FieldTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Form> Forms { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<FormField> FormFields { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SubmittedFieldValue> SubmittedFieldValues { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AuditTrail> AuditTrails { get; set; }

    public virtual ObjectResult<usp_FieldTypes_GetAll_Result> usp_FieldTypes_GetAll()
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<usp_FieldTypes_GetAll_Result>("usp_FieldTypes_GetAll");
    }

    public virtual int usp_FormField_Delete(Nullable<int> formFieldID, Nullable<System.Guid> userID)
    {
        var formFieldIDParameter = formFieldID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("FormFieldID", formFieldID) :
            new ObjectParameter("FormFieldID", typeof(int));

        var userIDParameter = userID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserID", userID) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserID", typeof(System.Guid));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("usp_FormField_Delete", formFieldIDParameter, userIDParameter);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<usp_FormField_GetAllByFormID_Result> usp_FormField_GetAllByFormID(Nullable<int> formID)
    {
        var formIDParameter = formID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("FormID", formID) :
            new ObjectParameter("FormID", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<usp_FormField_GetAllByFormID_Result>("usp_FormField_GetAllByFormID", formIDParameter);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<usp_FormField_Insert_Result> usp_FormField_Insert(Nullable<int> formID, string fieldType, string fieldName, Nullable<int> fieldOrder, string displayText, string listValues, Nullable<System.Guid> userID)
    {
        var formIDParameter = formID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("FormID", formID) :
            new ObjectParameter("FormID", typeof(int));

        var fieldTypeParameter = fieldType != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("FieldType", fieldType) :
            new ObjectParameter("FieldType", typeof(string));

        var fieldNameParameter = fieldName != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("FieldName", fieldName) :
            new ObjectParameter("FieldName", typeof(string));

        var fieldOrderParameter = fieldOrder.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("FieldOrder", fieldOrder) :
            new ObjectParameter("FieldOrder", typeof(int));

        var displayTextParameter = displayText != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("DisplayText", displayText) :
            new ObjectParameter("DisplayText", typeof(string));

        var listValuesParameter = listValues != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("ListValues", listValues) :
            new ObjectParameter("ListValues", typeof(string));

        var userIDParameter = userID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserID", userID) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserID", typeof(System.Guid));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<usp_FormField_Insert_Result>("usp_FormField_Insert", formIDParameter, fieldTypeParameter, fieldNameParameter, fieldOrderParameter, displayTextParameter, listValuesParameter, userIDParameter);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<usp_FormField_Update_Result> usp_FormField_Update(Nullable<int> formID, Nullable<int> formFieldID, string fieldType, string fieldName, Nullable<int> fieldOrder, string displayText, string listValues, Nullable<System.Guid> userID)
    {
        var formIDParameter = formID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("FormID", formID) :
            new ObjectParameter("FormID", typeof(int));

        var formFieldIDParameter = formFieldID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("FormFieldID", formFieldID) :
            new ObjectParameter("FormFieldID", typeof(int));

        var fieldTypeParameter = fieldType != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("FieldType", fieldType) :
            new ObjectParameter("FieldType", typeof(string));

        var fieldNameParameter = fieldName != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("FieldName", fieldName) :
            new ObjectParameter("FieldName", typeof(string));

        var fieldOrderParameter = fieldOrder.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("FieldOrder", fieldOrder) :
            new ObjectParameter("FieldOrder", typeof(int));

        var displayTextParameter = displayText != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("DisplayText", displayText) :
            new ObjectParameter("DisplayText", typeof(string));

        var listValuesParameter = listValues != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("ListValues", listValues) :
            new ObjectParameter("ListValues", typeof(string));

        var userIDParameter = userID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserID", userID) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserID", typeof(System.Guid));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<usp_FormField_Update_Result>("usp_FormField_Update", formIDParameter, formFieldIDParameter, fieldTypeParameter, fieldNameParameter, fieldOrderParameter, displayTextParameter, listValuesParameter, userIDParameter);
    }

    public virtual int usp_Forms_Delete(Nullable<int> formID, Nullable<System.Guid> userID)
    {
        var formIDParameter = formID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("FormID", formID) :
            new ObjectParameter("FormID", typeof(int));

        var userIDParameter = userID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserID", userID) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserID", typeof(System.Guid));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("usp_Forms_Delete", formIDParameter, userIDParameter);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<usp_Forms_GetAll_Result> usp_Forms_GetAll()
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<usp_Forms_GetAll_Result>("usp_Forms_GetAll");
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<usp_Forms_GetByID_Result> usp_Forms_GetByID(Nullable<int> formID)
    {
        var formIDParameter = formID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("FormID", formID) :
            new ObjectParameter("FormID", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<usp_Forms_GetByID_Result>("usp_Forms_GetByID", formIDParameter);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<usp_Forms_Insert_Result> usp_Forms_Insert(string formName, Nullable<int> clientID, Nullable<System.Guid> userID)
    {
        var formNameParameter = formName != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("FormName", formName) :
            new ObjectParameter("FormName", typeof(string));

        var clientIDParameter = clientID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("ClientID", clientID) :
            new ObjectParameter("ClientID", typeof(int));

        var userIDParameter = userID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserID", userID) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserID", typeof(System.Guid));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<usp_Forms_Insert_Result>("usp_Forms_Insert", formNameParameter, clientIDParameter, userIDParameter);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<usp_Forms_Update_Result> usp_Forms_Update(Nullable<int> formID, string formName, Nullable<System.Guid> userID)
    {
        var formIDParameter = formID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("FormID", formID) :
            new ObjectParameter("FormID", typeof(int));

        var formNameParameter = formName != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("FormName", formName) :
            new ObjectParameter("FormName", typeof(string));

        var userIDParameter = userID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserID", userID) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserID", typeof(System.Guid));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<usp_Forms_Update_Result>("usp_Forms_Update", formIDParameter, formNameParameter, userIDParameter);
    }

    public virtual int usp_Logs_Insert(string message, Nullable<System.DateTime> logDate, Nullable<int> clientID)
    {
        var messageParameter = message != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("Message", message) :
            new ObjectParameter("Message", typeof(string));

        var logDateParameter = logDate.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("LogDate", logDate) :
            new ObjectParameter("LogDate", typeof(System.DateTime));

        var clientIDParameter = clientID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("ClientID", clientID) :
            new ObjectParameter("ClientID", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("usp_Logs_Insert", messageParameter, logDateParameter, clientIDParameter);
    }

    public virtual int usp_SubmittedFieldValues_Insert(Nullable<int> formID)
    {
        var formIDParameter = formID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("FormID", formID) :
            new ObjectParameter("FormID", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("usp_SubmittedFieldValues_Insert", formIDParameter);
    }
}
```

Structure map registry

```
public class ApplicationDBContextRegistry : Registry
{
    public ApplicationDBContextRegistry()
    {
        For<IApplicationDbContext>().Use<ApplicationDbContext>().ContainerScoped();

    }
}
```

startup

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(SteadyHOPS.Startup))]
namespace SteadyHOPS
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
    public IContainer Container
    {
        get
        {
            return (IContainer)HttpContext.Current.Items["_Container"];
        }
        set
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Items["_Container"] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Items["_Container"] = value;
            }
        }
    }


    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(
           new StructureMapDependencyResolver(() => Container ?? IoC.Container));

        IoC.Container.Configure(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddRegistry(new StandardRegistry());
            cfg.AddRegistry(new ControllerRegistry());
            cfg.AddRegistry(new ActionFilterRegistry(
                () => Container ?? IoC.Container));
            cfg.AddRegistry(new MvcRegistry());
            cfg.AddRegistry(new TaskRegistry());
            cfg.AddRegistry(new ModelMetadataRegistry());
            cfg.AddRegistry(new ApplicationDBContextRegistry());
        });

        IoC.Container.Configure(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddRegistry(new DBContextRegistry(
                () => Container ?? IoC.Container));
        });

        IoC.Container.Configure(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddRegistry(new IdentityRegistry(
                () => Container ?? IoC.Container));
        });
```

another related registry

```
public class DBContextRegistry : Registry
{
    public DBContextRegistry(Func<IContainer> _container)
    {
        var container = _container();
        //ApplicationDbContext context = (ApplicationDbContext)container.GetInstance<IApplicationDbContext>();
        For<DbContext>().Use((ApplicationDbContext)container.GetInstance<IApplicationDbContext>()).ContainerScoped();

    }
}
```

identity registry

```
  public class IdentityRegistry : Registry
    {
    public IdentityRegistry(Func<IContainer> _container)
    {

        var container = _container();
        var args = new ExplicitArguments();
        args.Set<DbContext>((ApplicationDbContext)container.GetInstance<IApplicationDbContext>());


        //UserStore<ApplicationUser> store = (UserStore<ApplicationUser>)container.GetInstance<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(args);



        For<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().Use(() => new UserStore<ApplicationUser>((ApplicationDbContext)container.GetInstance<IApplicationDbContext>())).ContainerScoped();
        //For<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().Use(container.GetInstance<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(args)).ContainerScoped();

        //For<IOwinContext>().Use();
        For<Microsoft.Owin.Security.IAuthenticationManager>().Use(() => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).ContainerScoped();
        For<IApplicationUserManager>().Use<ApplicationUserManager>().ContainerScoped(); //( UserStore<ApplicationUser>((ApplicationDbContext)container.GetInstance<IApplicationDbContext>())));
        For<IApplicationSignInManager>().Use<ApplicationSignInManager>().ContainerScoped();
    }
}
```

current user class

```
public class CurrentUser : ICurrentUser
{
    private readonly IIdentity _identity;
    private readonly ApplicationUserManager _manager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    private ApplicationUser _user;



    public CurrentUser(IIdentity identity, IApplicationUserManager manager, IApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _identity = identity;
        _manager = (ApplicationUserManager)manager;
        _context = (ApplicationDbContext)context;

        try
        {
            var test = _manager.Users.FirstOrDefault(); // this fails using the domain connection string but succeeds using identity one
            var test2 = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(); // this fails using the domain connection string but succeeds using identity one
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }

    public ApplicationUser User
    {
        get { return  _user ?? (_user = _manager.FindById(_identity.GetUserId())); }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a pretty good walkthrough on how to set this up [here](https://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/). It doesn't have a StructureMap example, but it should be fairly easy to work it out based on the other examples.

Comment: One huge issue I see is that you are trying to access the user from the *constructor*. Never do this. In ASP.NET, the user is not populated that early in the request life cycle.